# Can I increment values in a SQL record using an update?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to do something like the following (in Sql Server):

```
update person set numItems += @num, today = @updateDate where id = @id
```

I know the "numItems += @num" is not correct syntax, how do I write that part?

Comment: Since SQL Server 2008, the *Add Equals* operator and kin has been supported by SQL Server 2008: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627392(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have a `+=` notation, so just expand it fully

```
update person set numItems = numItems + @num, today = @updateDate where id = @id
```

Answer (score 1):

Some databases do support `+=`.  However, the following is standard SQL:

```
update person
    set numItems = numItems + @num,
        today = @updateDate
where id = @id;
```

Comment: "*Some databases do support +=*" - really? Which one?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL Server 2008+